# Recurrence on partial orders

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Let $P_n$ denote the number of partial orders on $n$ elements.

A partial order is a relation that is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

$P_n$ is known for $n; 0\leq n\leq 18$. See [On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=A001035&sort=&language=english&go=Search).
I have seen other combinatorial sequences which can be computed recursively from previous terms. For example [this somewhat related sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4249132/11619). Is there a way to do this with the number of partial orders?

Can I get $P_{19}$ from the available values of $P_n$? How?

Comment: I note that there is a meta thread concerning this question, in particular, whether or not it should be deleted: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/why-was-this-question-and-its-answer-deleted-and-how-to-undelete-it

Comment: I think that adding the link to OEIS is very relevant here. It unambiguously implies that this is a difficult open problem. True, this is anything but the most lucid of questions, but the OP seems to be gone.

Comment: Note : Had voted to delete this question prior to the undeletion and edit : agree with both nature of context rewrite as well as reopening as it stands. The question is now open.

Answer (score 6):

No recurrence is known that would allow you to take just the *numbers* $P_1,\ldots,P_{18}$ and calculate $P_{19}$.

There are recursive techniques for counting partial orders (see Brinkmann & McKay 2002), but they work by actually *listing* possible partial orders of a certain size, then trying out the possibilities where another element can be placed.

This does not lead to a simple recurrence on $P_n$ because *different* $n$-element partial orders will in general have *different* numbers of such extensions into $(n+1)$-element partial orders. You can observe this already going from $P_2=3$ to $P_3=19$. One of the 2-element orders extends to **seven** 3-element orders, but two of them extend to **six** each, for a total of $7+6+6=19$. In a nutshell, you end up applying the [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) instead of the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). (There are *some* nontrivial things for making it faster; see the B&M paper.)

So how to calculate $P_{19}$? Either spend perhaps $100\,000$ cpu years with the best algorithm currently known, or invent a better one.

- *Brinkmann, Gunnar; McKay, Brendan D.*, [**Posets on up to 16 points**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1016543307592), Order 19, No. 2, 147-179 (2002). [ZBL1006.06003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1006.06003).

**P.S.** It may be useful to note that MSE has several questions about the number of partial orders. [Searching MSE for A001035](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=a001035) gives 7 results at the moment.