# Recurrence relation on $a_n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence relation$$
a_{n}=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
t
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{n-t-1} 2^{t(n-t)} a_{t}, \quad a_{0}=1
$$
with $a_0=1$, I tried to evaluate $a_3$, and I got it equal to $25$, but the book shows it equal to $19$.

My effort: $a_1=1, a_2=3$ gives

$$a_3=\binom{3}{0}\times (-1)^2\times 2^0\times 1+\binom{3}{1}\times (-1)^1\times 2^2\times 1+\binom{3}{2}\times (-1)^0\times 2^2\times 3\\=1-12+36=25$$

Here is the text from the book (**Handbook of Enumerative Combinatorics by Miklos Bona**)

A very classical problem is to enumerate acyclic digraphs; they are clearly loopless and given two distinct vertices $u$ and $v$, only one of the two arcs $u v$ and $v u$ can be present. Let $a_{n}$ be the number of acyclic digraphs on $n$ labeled vertices, and let $a_{n, m}$ be the number of those having $m$ arcs. There is a simple recurrence for computing these numbers, found independently in and rediscovered several times. The number of acyclic digraphs such that $k$ given vertices are sources is equal to $2^{k(n-k)} a_{n-k}$ since the remaining $n-k$ vertices induce an acyclic digraph and every arc from the sources to the complement is allowed. Given that an acyclic digraph always has at least one source, inclusion-exclusion gives
$$
a_{n}=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
t
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{n-t-1} 2^{t(n-t)} a_{t}, \quad a_{0}=1
$$
This gives the sequence
$$
1,1,3,19,219,4231,130023, \ldots
$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your attempt? How exactly did you calculate $a_3$? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Sure. I shall share it.

Comment: Actually, having done the calculations, I also get $a_3=25$. All your calculations seem correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, your book has the wrong result. Using your recurrence relation, I get

$$\begin{align}a_{1}=\sum_{t=0}^{0}{1 \choose t}(-1)^{1-t-1} 2^{t(1-t)} a_{t} = {1\choose 0}\cdot (-1)^0\cdot 2^0\cdot a_0=a_0=1\end{align}$$

and then

$$\begin{align}a_2 = \sum_{t=0}^{1}{2 \choose t}(-1)^{2-t-1} 2^{t(2-t)} a_{t} &= {2 \choose 0}(-1)^{2-0-1} 2^{0(2-0)} a_{0} + {2 \choose 1}(-1)^{2-1-1} 2^{1(2-1)} a_{1}\\&=1\cdot (-1)\cdot 1\cdot a_0 + 2\cdot 1\cdot 2 \cdot a_1 = -a_0+4a_1=3\end{align}$$

and then I get the same value of $a_3$ as you.

It also seems like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Combinatorial_enumeration) agrees with the number 25, not the number 19. So does the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003024).

Comment: I have added the text from the book.

Comment: @IbadulQadeer The book appears to be wrong, see my edited answer.

Comment: But the subscripts are different for the Wikipedia link.

Comment: @IbadulQadeer The recurrence equation is different because of different subscripts, but the end result is the same.

Comment: @IbadulQadeer After some more searching around, I am positive that 25 is the correct answer. Comparing the wikipedia recurrence relation and the one you posted, they are equivalent and return the same result.

Comment: Seems to be a confusion between **acyclic digraphs** (A003024: 1,1,3,25,543,....) and **acyclic transitive digraphs** (A001035: 1,1,3,19,219,...).

Answer (score 2):

The Bona Handbook states on page 427

> This gives the sequence
> $$1,1,3,19,219,4231,130023,\dots,$$
> which is sequence A001035.

The [OEIS sequence A001035](https://oeis.org/A001035) entry states that
this is the number of labeled acyclic **transitive** digraphs
and the Bona Handbook is the second reference. Tellingly, there is **no** formula or recurrence for the sequence in the entry.
As several people noted, the recurrence is for [OEIS sequence A003024](https://oeis.org/A003024) "Number of acyclic digraphs with n labeled nodes". The first formula is essentially the recurrence given. The difference between the two sequences is the requirement of being
transitive. Somehow Bona got confused about that.

Comparing the sequences gives the table
$$ \begin{matrix}
n   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3  & 4   & 5     & 6       & 7\\
a_n & 1 & 1 & 3 & 25 & 543 & 29281 & 3781503 & 1138779265\\
b_n & 1 & 1 & 3 & 19 & 215 & 4231  & 130023  & 6129859
\end{matrix}$$
where the second sequence is for **transitive** digraphs. This
requirement reduces the count.